# What happens when I quit VACUUM in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, vacuum

I have a sqlite3 database > 34-GB. 
When I execute explicit `VACUUM` command for this db, the procedure takes too long time. So I want to know what happens when I force it to quit `VACUUM` task.

Is it OK to think `VACUUM` as atomic transaction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VACUUM first creates a new, temporary database file, and then overwrites the original database file. Everything is done inside a transaction using the standard mechanism for changing the database (rollback journal or WAL), so you can abort it at any time.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful information for me right now.

Comment: doesn't `VACUUM` command work out of a transaction ? I mean, try to launch `VACUUM` inside an explicit transaction. It is going to fail. It is written in [https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html](official docs).

Comment: @VanechikSpace VACUUM uses a transaction, but you cannot combine the changes done its transaction with any other transaction.

Comment: @CL. So what about VACUUM INTO ? Transactions are ACID which imply that there can be no intermediate state. Nevertheless, VACUUM INTO can produce a corrupted intermediate result due to some crash. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html

Comment: @VanechikSpace The source database is read in a transaction (so it is in a consistent state). The destination does not yet exist, so it cannot have a concurrent transaction.